# How to order a list by date (and/or minute and seconds) in C#

Tags: c#, list, sql-order-by

I need to order a list of elements by date.

This lamba function works well, but if two elements have the same date it doesn't.

```
orderList.Sort((x, y) => y.Value.CreationDate.CompareTo(x.Value.CreationDate));
```

where CreationDate is a DateTime value.

Suppose, for example, that two elements have the same creation date (09/05/2011). I would be able to distinguish minute (or maybe seconds).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's a `DateTime` value which includes the minutes/seconds, that should work fine already...

Comment: not sure what your goal is... please show some sample data and expected result... one point though: are all CreationDate in the same Timezone ?

Comment: No chance to order by minute or seconds. The result is no the expected one. Is there another mechanism to do this? It seems that CompareTo functions works only on a first level. The date one. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I've found the error. The date is correct. Hours, minute and seconds are with default values: **00:00:00**.

Comment: var result = orderList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime already contains the hours, minutes and seconds. If they are not available in your CreationDate value, then there is nothing you can sort based on. If, in fact, the data is there, than you should have no problem sorting as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

As it implement IComparable you don't need that lambda, only call orederList.Sort()